# Is `app.use('/:module')` a safe pattern to use in Express?

Tags: node.js, security, express

In my express application I want to use nested routing. I want to have a directory of modules that a user could add to (to enable extra functionality). I want to route to the correct module using the following pattern:

```
app.use('/:module', function(req, res) {
  var module_router = require('/path/to/modules/'+req.params.module+'/router.js');
  app.use(req.params.module, module_router);
}
```

This passes the request to the correct module router - and it doesn't rely on knowing which modules are available in the main code. My question is: can I rely on the contents of `:module` being safe (ie only alphanumeric). I'm just wondering if a nasty person could put the html escape sequence for '../' in or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter values are basically any character except `/`.

You could pre-load all modules ahead of time into an object which you can then safely do a lookup inside your middleware.

You could also use the built-in [path](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html) module like:

```
var normalize = require('path').normalize;

var basePath = '/path/to/modules/';

function getRouter(moduleName) {
  var origPath = basePath + moduleName + '/router.js',
      path = normalize(origPath),
      ret;
  if (path.indexOf(basePath) !== 0)
    return;
  try {
    ret = require(path);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return ret;
}

app.use('/:module', function(req, res) {
  var module_router = getRouter(req.params.module);
  if (module_router)
    app.use(req.params.module, module_router);
  else
    res.send(400);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I decided to take your first suggestion about pre-loading the modules (this bypasses the problem altogether). I still don't understand nested app.uses, because they are declarative rather than procedural.

Comment: @derekdreery For the nested middleware problem, you could add `next` to your route handler's parameter list and then simply do `module_router(req, res, next);`

Comment: Aah I was wondering if you could call the router as a function. Inspecting it suggested you could. I couldn't find this in the docs, although I guess this is an edge case.

Comment: Needing to do a lookup of directories asynchronously led me to learn about 'fibers', which is an awesomely useful library I recommend to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a RegEx check inside your middleware or use [app.param()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) to ensure it's alphanumeric.

Even if it passes the alphanumeric test, if the evaluated path in your `require()` does not exist, it will throw an error. Do a test first if the file exists.

Comment: Is a regex check fast? Can I get away with not doing it (if it's already done I don't want to do it again)

Comment: I don't know if Express does some kind of RegEx to clean up URLs. But it does try to match the incoming request with any path that you defined.

Comment: Did a test... the request `/favicon.ico` and `/foo.jpg` matched the pattern `/:module`.

Comment: Thanks - then I might need to regex and next() it if it doesn't match (although this will be the last route it is possible to hit). Having messed about for a bit, I'm not sure the nested `app.use` works, so I need to look at that as well.